# Extracting Blank Frames from Imported Video

Tags: image-processing, frame

Go easy on me; it's my first question. But please do let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

When using VideoExtractFrames, I'm getting blank and black frames from my video. I get the same problem with VideoFrameList.

It's not clear what's happening. Perhaps the RAWVIDEO encoding, aspect ratio, or the 170 fps frame rate is the problem. Previous .avi files have worked, which leads me to believe I have a problem that will potentially repeat itself at the worst possible time.

The weird part? I can apply RangeFilter just fine using VideoFrameMap.

Here's what I get when pulling meta info:

```
originalVideo =   Import["C:\\Users\\santi\\Downloads\\newbubb.avi", "MetaInformation"] 

<|"ApproximateFrameCount" -> 5513, 
     "ResourcePath" -> File["C:\\Users\\santi\\Downloads\\newbubb.avi"], 
     "Duration" -> Quantity[36.752, "Seconds"], 
     "BitRate" -> Quantity[576342381, ("Bits")/("Seconds")], 
     "VideoTracks" -> <|1 -> <|"FrameRate" -> 
          Quantity[5000000/33333, ("Frames")/("Seconds")], 
         "BitDepth" -> 8, "ColorSpace" -> "GrayScale", 
         "VideoEncoding" -> "RAWVIDEO", "PixelFormat" -> "pal8", 
         "PixelAspectRatio" -> 1, "RasterSize" -> {600, 800}|>|>|>
```

Things that don't work as expected:

```
VideoFrameList[originalVideo, 10]
VideoExtractFrames[originalVideo, 270]
```

Comment: Can you try with this avi: https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2018/04/file_example_AVI_480_750kB.avi if the issue appears with that sample avi, then at least we have some data to replicate the problem. Note, it's not rawvideo, but if you can reproduce the issue, it's unlikely encoding is a problem.

Comment: ^^ I converted the sample above to rawvideo with ffmpeg, but it still worked. Then I used `fmt pal8` instead of yuv420p and I got the black frames. I think the problem lies with pal8, which incidentally does not play in VLC for me either. I then re-converted the pal8 video back into yuv420p and it importing it and extracting a frame worked in Mathematica: `ffmpeg -i pal8video.avi  -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p yuvvideo.avi`

Comment: Wow thank you for the response @flinty !  I'll see if this works on my video right now.

Comment: It worked! I will see what I can do about the recordings. Thank you for the help!